# Run time error 91 in vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Hvalue As Double
Dim Svalue As Double
Set rng = Selection

Hvalue = 0
Svalue = 0
For Each cell In rng

Next cell
If cell.Value > Hvalue Then Hvalue = cell.Value 'here i get run time error 91
For Each cell In rng
Next cell
If cell.Value < Hvalue And cell.Value > Svalue Then cell.Value = Svalue


MsgBox "hvalue= " & Hvalue & "svalue=" & Svalue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because the variable `cell` is only valid locally inside the loop and your if statement is outside the loop.  Move your if statements inside the loop like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Hvalue As Double
    Dim Svalue As Double
    Set rng = Selection

    Hvalue = 0
    Svalue = 0

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value > Hvalue Then Hvalue = cell.Value
    Next cell

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value < Hvalue And cell.Value > Svalue Then cell.Value = Svalue
    Next cell

    MsgBox "hvalue= " & Hvalue & "svalue=" & Svalue
End Sub
```